# preg_replace spaces with numbers

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to preg_replace all-spaces in my text with different following numbers?

as

```
{"id":" "},{"id":" "},{"id":" "},
```

to be

```
{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},
```

Comment: Is the input string JSON?

Comment: yes just JSON like the example

Comment: Why use a regex? Decode it an iterate through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$text = '{"id":" "},{"id":" "},{"id":" "},';
$count = 0;
$text = preg_replace_callback('/" "(?=})/', function ($m) use(&$count){
    return ++$count;
}, $text);

print_r($text);
```

The output:

```
{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},
```

---

If there's a real need to enclose the digits with double quotes replace the return expression of the callback with the following:

```
    return '"' . ++$count . '"';
```

Comment: Great Thanks , You saved my day :)

Comment: Can you check this question also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420319/preg-replace-null-with-specific-data?noredirect=1#comment70046047_41420319