# preg_replace null with specific data

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to use `preg_replace` to replace `null` words in my text with a url ending with user's name?

For example:

Replace `null` in this

```
(1, 3, 'sam', 'sam-website', 'yes', 'null'), (2, 3, 'alex', 'alex-website', 'yes', 'null'), (3, 3, 'kabor', 'kabor-website', 'yes', 'null'),
```

to get this

```
(1, 3, 'sam', 'sam-website', 'yes', 'http://mywebsite.com/pics.php?id=sam'), (2, 3, 'alex', 'alex-website', 'yes', 'http://mywebsite.com/pics.php?id=alex'), (3, 3, 'kabor', 'kabor-website', 'yes', 'http://mywebsite.com/pics.php?id=kabor'),
```

tried this but it doesn't work

```
$name = preg_match('/3, \'(.*?)\',/im', $string, $matches);

$url = preg_replace_callback('/null(?=)/', function ($name){
    return ($matches[1]);
}, $string);
```

Comment: Which format *that* data is in? You should manipulate the data **before** it comes to the *null* format.

Comment: its a JSON format

Comment: Please show us the code through which you're getting this *null* formatted data. Like I said, it'd be easier for you if you manipulate and format data beforehand.

Comment: this is a json object again , all i need is to preg_replace last field with my url ending with username

Comment: @chris85 Great Thanks , Worked Perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is a bit off. The `im` modifiers aren't doing anything and your current capturing mechanics won't allow you to separate the name and `NULL` value. Additionally the `return` isn't doing anything and the `$name` is only going to be `0` or `1` (`$matches` is the captured value).

I would pull all values between the parenthesis then use a CSV parser to get each data point. From there you can rebuild your string and return it.

Here's an example:

```
$string = "(1, 3, 'sam', 'sam-website', 'yes', 'null'), (2, 3, 'alex', 'alex-website', 'yes', 'null'), (3, 3, 'kabor', 'kabor-website', 'yes', 'null'),";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\(([^)]+)/', function ($match) {
      $data = str_getcsv($match[1], ',', "'");
      $return = '(';
      foreach($data as $key => $element) {
           if(is_numeric($element)) {
                  $return .= $element;
           } else {
                if($key == (count($data) - 1)) {
                     $return .= "'http://mywebsite.com/pics.php?id=" . $data[2] . "'";
                } else {
                      $return .= "'" . $element . "'";
                }
            }
           $return .= ', ';
      }
      return rtrim($return, ', ');
 }, $string);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/707446

Comment: Great Thanks , Worked Perfectly!